# Haskell: making a deck of cards

Tags: list, haskell

I am new to Haskell and having problems using recursion to make a deck of cards.

I have all these definitions:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven
              | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen
              | King | Ace

type Card = (Suit, Value)
type Deck = [Card]

instance Show Suit where
   show Club = "Club"
   show Diamond = "Diamond"
   show Heart = "Heart"
   show Spade = "Spade"

instance Show Value where
  show Two = "Two"
  show Three = "Three"
  show Four = "Four"
  show Five = "Five"
  show Six = "Six"
  show Seven = "Seven"
  show Eight = "Eight"
  show Nine = "Nine"
  show Ten = "Ten"
  show Jack = "Jack"
  show Queen = "Queen"
  show King = "King"
  show Ace = "Ace"
```

I am trying to write a function

```
makeDeck :: Deck
```

which returns a list of cards in the order the Data is given, so (Club, Two - Ace), (Diamond, Two-Ace), etc.

I want to do this using recursion, which is why I am having so much difficulty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a tip - you don't need to define those instances of `Show` yourself. If you just put `deriving Show` at the end of the datatype declaration, it'll do all that for you.

Comment: Why using recursion?  There are much better ways of doing this, unless this is homework...

Comment: Also, if this isn't homework: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HCard

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't use recursion, but a more canonical way of doing this is:

Add `deriving Enum` to the definition of Suit and Value, then:

```
makeDeck :: Deck
makeDeck = [(suit, value) | suit <- [Club..Spade], value <- [Two..Ace]]
```

Alternatively, provide fully defined lists of all suits and values rather than using `Enum`.

Comment: Or with the power of `Applicative`s, `makeDeck = (,) <$> [Club ..] <*> [Two ..]`

Comment: since they instance `Enum`, you can just do `[minBound..maxBound]` instead of `[Club..Spade]` or `[Two..Ace]`

Comment: @newacct: that requires a `Bounded` instance as well, which can also be derived.

Comment: If Haskell complains "A section must be enclosed in parentheses", you need to add spaces around the `..`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261345/why-haskell-range-needs-spaces-when-using-lt-gt (at the least you need one space before it)

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade   deriving (Show, Enum)

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven
          | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen
          | King | Ace  deriving (Show, Enum)

type Card = (Suit, Value)
type Deck = [Card]

makeDeck :: Deck
```

there are lots of ways to calculate a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) -- the product of sets.
All of the functions used in these examples can be looked up on Hoogle:

### Monads

Using do notation:

```
makeDeck = do
    suit <- [Club ..]
    value <- [Two ..]
    return (suit, value)
```

The unsugared form of the above, which uses `>>=`:

```
makeDeck = [Club ..] >>= \suit ->
    [Two ..] >>= \value ->
    return (suit, value)
```

Lifting:

```
makeDeck = liftM2 (,) [Club ..] [Two ..]
```

Function application within monads:

```
makeDeck = return (,) `ap` [Club ..] `ap` [Two ..]
```

### Applicatives

Lifting:

```
makeDeck = liftA2 (,) [Club ..] [Two ..]
```

Function application within applicatives:

```
makeDeck = pure (,) <*> [Club ..] <*> [Two ..]
```

Which is the same as:

```
makeDeck = (,) <$> [Club ..] <*> [Two ..]
```

### List comprehensions

See @ivanm's answers.

### Without any type classes

```
makeDeck = concatMap (\suit -> map ((,) suit) [Two ..]) [Club ..]
```

If you need to use recursion explicitly, you can replace `concatMap` with its [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#concatMap), and so on until you get to `foldr`, where the real recursive action happens.

Comment: This is exactly the same as doing it with a list comprehension, just using Monadic syntax.

Comment: @ivanm -- it's not exactly the same.  I'd agree that it's similar on a syntax level, but for a Haskell newbie (me), list comprehensions are something baked-in (and only apply to lists), whereas monads are part of a deeper concept.  Thus, it's actually quite a leap to say, "you know what, I'm going to replace this list comprehension with a monad".  Maybe as I learn more, that distinction will fade away.

Comment: list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for the list monad; in general we even have monad comprehensions: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/MonadComprehensions

Comment: OK, missed where you said that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you aware of [list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) and all the awesome things you can do with them? The `makeDeck` function could be written as a fairly simple list comprehension (as ivanm pointed out in his answer), especially given the order you'd like the deck to be in.

However, if you'd still like to use recursion, there are a few ways to go about it. First, figure out what variables you'll need to keep track of during the whole operation. You'll need to keep the current list of cards, and a record of which suit and value you're at. So the type signature might look something like `makeDeck :: Suit -> Value -> Deck`. Then you'd want to use pattern matching to handle the several possible cases during the computation, such as

```
makeDeck suit Ace deck = (suit,Ace):(makeDeck (succ suit) Two)
[...]
```

As you can see, this might turn out to be a fairly long and unwieldy definition. The list comprehension method would yield a much more short, elegant, and canonical solution. Regardless of which you choose, you'll need to add `deriving Enum` to the end of your datatype declarations. Read up on the `deriving` keyword [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Class_declarations#Deriving) or elsewhere online if you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed you towards list comprehensions, but if you would like to write it recursively, read on.
This sounds like homework, so I'll just try and give you tips that point you in the right direction (as opposed to writing it for you).

Thing to realize #1:
If you derive the Enum typeclass for your algebraic data types, you can create enumerations like so:

```
*Main> [Club .. Spade]
[Club,Diamond,Heart,Spade]
```

Thing to realize #2:
You can create lists of tuples like that, by using maps. You'll end up with [[Suit]], so you should use the `concat` function to join them into a `Deck`.

```
*Main> concat $ map (\x -> map (\y -> (x, y)) ['a'..'c']) [1..3]
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c'),(3,'a'),(3,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

Thing to realize #3:
You can implement map recursively. Here's the definition from the Prelude:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

So you could write the (map . map) as one big recursive function. Good luck!

Comment: There's also `concatMap` instead of `concat . map f`.