# Why Haskell range needs spaces when using [LT .. GT]?

Tags: haskell

Why is it that when I do range in Haskell, this works:

```
[LT .. GT]
```

but this doesn't:

```
[LT..GT]
```

and what does this cryptic error mean:

```
<interactive>:1:2:
    Failed to load interface for `LT':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

<interactive>:1:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (`LT..` GT)
```

However, When I use Ints, the second form (without spaces) works:

```
[1..3]
```

Comment: What error message do you get? I got a fairly useful one when I tried it...

Comment: GHCi accept it resulting `[1,2,3]`. Maybe some other compiler read `1.` as floating point and then it's loose for it any sense.

Comment: @Hauleth: Actually it did work for `[1..3]`, your explanation can only tell why it would not work.

Comment: I said that in GHC it works. Maybe in any other Haskell compiler it is parsed as I said.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's because `LT..` is interpreted as the `.` operator in the `LT` module.

---

```
<interactive>:1:2:
    Failed to load interface for `LT':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

It means GHC cannot find a module named `LT`. The same message appears if you use a qualified name with a non-existing library:

```
Prelude> SDJKASD.sdfhj

<interactive>:1:1:
    Failed to load interface for `SDJKASD':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

---

```
<interactive>:1:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (`LT..` GT)
```

In Haskell, a [section](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html) is an infix operator with a partial application, e.g. `(* 3)`, which is equivalent to `\x -> x * 3`.

In your case, `LT..` is interpreted as an infix `.` operator, and the `GT` is part of the section formed with this operator.

A section must be enclosed in parenthesis, and since the misinterpretation does not, the parser will complain like this.

Another example of the error:

```
Prelude> [* 3]

<interactive>:1:2:
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (* 3)
```

Comment: ... and module names may not be of the form `[0-9]+.*`, so there's no ambiguity with numbers.

Answer (score 16):

Because of the [maximal munch rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch), `LT..` gets interpreted as the qualified name of the `(.)` operator in the `LT` module. Since you can define your own operators in Haskell, the language allows you to fully qualify the names of operators in the same way as you can with functions.

This leads to an ambiguity with the `..` used in ranges when the name of the operator starts with `.`, which is resolved by using the maximal munch rule, which says that the longest match wins.

For example, `Prelude..` is the qualified name of the function composition operator.

```
> :info Prelude..
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c   -- Defined in GHC.Base
infixr 9 .
> (+3) Prelude.. (*2) $ 42
87
```

The reason why `[1..3]` or `[x..y]` works, is because a module name must begin with an upper case letter, so `1..` and `x..` cannot be qualified names.

Comment: I see... but how would i know that I made such a mistake? I edited the question to show the error - can you explain it?

Comment: @drozzy: The error message could have been better here. "Cannot load interface for LT" basically means "Could not find the module LT", which I suppose would have made it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: The lexer [treats `LT..` differently from `LT ..`](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.4) (see table at the end of that section). The first error comes from the lack of `LT` (it's neither imported nor defined). With the second error, Haskell still assumes `LT..` is an operator with unspecified fixity (hence the inserted `\``); because it can't parse `[operator Identifier]`, it assumes `LT..GT` was actually an attempt to write `\x -> x \`LT..\` GT`, but that syntactic sugar may only be used when enclosed in parentheses: `[(\`LT..\` GT)]`.

Comment: @Tinctorius: Backticks are not used with operators, even if they are qualified. See my `Prelude..` example. The suggestion given in the error message is wrong and does not parse. If the newest GHC is giving that message, we should report it as a bug.

Comment: And that is yet another good reason to have spaces around `..` (although the ugliness of `[1..3]` should be enough ;).

Comment: @hammar: also happens on 7.2.1; reported as [#5657](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5657).

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to load interface for `LT':

Kenny and Hammar have explained what this means: `LT..` is assumed to be the `.` function in the `LT` module. Since there is no `LT` module, your interpreter naturally cannot load it.

> A section must be enclosed in parentheses thus: (`LT..` GT)

Along the same vein, assuming that `LT..` is a reference to the `.` function in the `LT` module, your interpreter is apparently assuming that you made the mistake of using square brackets instead of parens in order to for a "section" ( a section is, for example, `(+1)` ).

This is simply an obnoxious little wart in the Haskell language; just remember to use spaces.